# What is best way to implement calendar and time picker?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, timepicker

I have to implement `Calendar` and `TimePicker` I have attached image please see and give me answer what is the best way to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Please see this image

[image]

Comment: For first part you can use horizontal recyclerview. For second part you can use _NumberPicker_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date selection you can use HorizontalCalendarView from [Mulham-Raee](https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5087)  or HorizontalCalendarView from [mybringback22](https://github.com/mybringback22/HorizontalCalendarView-Android-?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7061) into your xml like.

```
<devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar.HorizontalCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:textColorNormal="#bababa"
            app:textColorSelected="#FFFF"
            app:selectorColor="#c62828"  //default to colorAccent
            app:selectedDateBackground="@drawable/myDrawable"/>
```

or

```
<com.view.calender.horizontal.umar.horizontalcalendarview.HorizontalCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalcalendarview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
 </com.view.calender.horizontal.umar.horizontalcalendarview.HorizontalCalendarView>
```

and for time picker you can use [androidTimePicker](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers). Also
there is [wheel picker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker) with this you can design your time picker like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timepicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
            android:id="@+id/hour"
            app:wheel_item_text_size="20sp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:wheel_item_space="10dp"
            app:wheel_same_width="true"
            app:wheel_atmospheric="true"
            app:wheel_curved="true"
            app:wheel_cyclic="true"
            app:wheel_item_align="right"
            app:wheel_item_text_color="#A7A7DB"
            app:wheel_selected_item_text_color="#536D8A"
            app:wheel_visible_item_count="3"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
            android:id="@+id/minute"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:wheel_item_space="10dp"
            app:wheel_same_width="true"
            app:wheel_atmospheric="true"
            app:wheel_curved="true"
            app:wheel_cyclic="true"
            app:wheel_item_text_color="#A7A7DB"
            app:wheel_item_text_size="20sp"
            app:wheel_selected_item_text_color="#536D8A"
            app:wheel_visible_item_count="3"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
            android:id="@+id/am_pm"
            app:wheel_item_text_size="20sp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:wheel_item_space="10dp"
            app:wheel_same_width="true"
            app:wheel_atmospheric="true"
            app:wheel_curved="true"
            app:wheel_item_align="right"
            app:wheel_item_text_color="#A7A7DB"
            app:wheel_selected_item_text_color="#536D8A"
            app:wheel_visible_item_count="2"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```